# select box in wordpress for meta field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am registering a post in my wp-admin but I don't want editor etc, so adding some field. By the R & D I founded how to add text box and it's awesome but now I have to add a select box and the option value should be post title. I don't want to do this by plugin.
I added text field as:

```
$client_meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'meta-client',
    'title' => __('Client Options','mfn-opts'),
    'page' => 'client',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(

        array(
            'id' => 'post-link',
            'type' => 'text',

            'title' => __('Link', 'opts'),
            'sub_desc' => __('Link to client`s site', 'opts'),
        ),

    ),
);
```

and I can add select box by just change the type as  `'type' => 'select'` but how did I get the post title value in option.

Comment: 1 downvote + pointed my fault, I am happy with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Using this to add meta box lile text, chackbox, selectoption.`**

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'meta-client',      // meta box id, unique per meta box
    'title' => 'Client Options',    // meta box title
    'pages' => array('client'), // post types, accept custom post types as well, 
                                    //default is array('post'); optional
    'priority' => 'high', // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
    'fields' => array( 
        array(  
            'label'=> 'Text Input',  
            'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'text',  
            'type'  => 'text'  
        ),  
        array(  
            'label'=> 'Textarea',  
            'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'textarea',  
            'type'  => 'textarea'  
        ),  
        array(  
            'label'=> 'Checkbox Input',  
            'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'checkbox',  
            'type'  => 'checkbox'  
        ),  
        array(  
            'label'=> 'Select Box',  
            'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'select',  
            'type'  => 'select',  
            'options' => array(
                       'option1' => 'Optionone',  // 'value'=>'label'
                       'option2' => 'Optiontwo',
                       'option3' => 'Optionthree'
                    )    
        )  
    );
```

Comment: i added your option value, its showing three array in dropdown not value like one, two, threee, and how can i get post title in options....thanks

Comment: +1 for how to add select box, and now how to get post title value in options...??